# How is this jquery plugin getting the current date?

Tags: jquery, date

In this plugin:

http://dansnetwork.com/2010/03/27/content-expirator-jquery-content-expiration-plugin/

He is comparing the expire date `d` to the current date `today`, but I don't understand how `today` knows what today's date is just from `new Date()`:

```
(function($){
$.contentExpirator = function(prfx){
    var pfix = prfx || 'exp';
    $("[class|="+pfix+"]").each(function(){
        var eString = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
        var dString = eString.split('-');
        var d = new Date(dString[1],dString[2].toString()-1,dString[3]);
        var today = new Date();
        if(d < today){
            $(this).css('display','none');
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

The code works fine, I'm just asking out of curiosity for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value for `new Date()` is the current date.  From the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date):

> If you supply no arguments, the constructor creates a Date object for today's date and time according to local time.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I have been looking at the documentation for date() alot lately and have skipped over that part everytime...